# react-leaflet version 2 --> 3 breaks code

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

This has been giving me problems over the last few days. Consider this simple code to change the color of the circles when you press the button.

```
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (color === "red") {
      setColor("blue");
    } else {
      setColor("red");
    }
  };

<button style={{ textAlign: "center" }} onClick={handleClick}>
        Click me to change colour!
</button>

 <MapContainer center={position} zoom={13} style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        {lightRailStop.features.map((feature, index) => {
          return (
            <Circle
              center={[
                feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
                feature.geometry.coordinates[0]
              ]}
              fillColor={color} //this part is set by a function
              radius={200}
              weight={1}
              opacity={1}
              fillOpacity={0.8}
            />
          );
        })}
      </MapContainer>
```

When you use `react-leaflet` v2, it works. However, v3 breaks this completely and I'm not sure why.

Would really appreciate help on this as im close to tearing my hair out trying to get simple things to work

codebox (can use the dependency box to change the version)
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-geojson-oneachfeature-popup-with-custom-react-component-forked-mx6pd8?file=/src/App.js

NOTE: `MapContainer` does not work for v2 -> need to replace with `Map`

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to fix this, but it is more a workaround than an official solution. Anyway, here is what I got:

First, in your component, define a ref, that will hold an array of Circle references:

```
const circleRefs = useRef();
circleRefs.current = [];
```

Then, when you create your circle, add the circle to the array of references (note that I added a key to your Circle component, since React wants every children of an array to be indexed with such a key):

```
<Circle
  key={index} // Add a key here
  center={[
    feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
    feature.geometry.coordinates[0]
  ]}
  fillColor={color}
  radius={200}
  weight={1}
  opacity={1}
  fillOpacity={0.8}
  ref={(ref) => { // Add the current circle to the references array
    circleRefs.current.push(ref);
  }}
/>
```

Then, since the map is not refreshed on the color change, handle the update manually like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  circleRefs.current.map((circle) => circle.setStyle({ fillColor: color }));
},[color]);
```

As I said, I have no clue if there is a better way to do this in a more reactive way (by just updating the color state, so the circle update themselves), but this solution does the job.

By the way, I can't make it work for the reat leaflet v2, I'm getting errors in your codesandbox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, MapContainer is new for react-leaflet v3, if you want it to work for v2, youd need to use Map instead. I see the workaround, was wondering why this behavior broke

Comment: Ah yes exact, thank you @Wboy! I checked the documentation, and found something interesting for you, check my other answer

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, in order to change the color of a Layer, you are supposed to set it through the [pathOptions](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components/#path-behavior), and not anymore with the `fillOptions`.
So in the end, your `Circle` component should look like this:

```
<Circle
  key={index}
  center={[
    feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
    feature.geometry.coordinates[0]
  ]}
  pathOptions={{ color }} // Use pathOptions
  radius={200}
  weight={1}
  opacity={1}
  fillOpacity={0.8}
/>
```

Actually, it is interesting to note that `fillOptions` still works, but it is unmutable, so it is not useful in your case (because it allows you to just set an initial value, but it can never be changed again).

Comment: Does this solve your issue @Wboy ?